# using Selenium Webdriver with CkEditor in Firefox 14

Tags: firefox, webdriver, ckeditor, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver in Java with Firefox 14.

My problem is that I can't seem to get webdriver to play nicely with CkEditor. I have looked for solutions but have been unable to get any working in either Firefox 13 or 14. These are the solutions that I have tried:

1. The normal sendKeys interction

   ```
   textArea.sendKeys();
   ```

   or

   ```
   textArea.click();
   textArea.sendKeys();
   ```

   **Result**: This code wouldn't produce any text in the CkEditor
2. The code from [Selenium issue 3890](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3890)

   ```
   d.get("http://ckeditor.com/demo");
   WebElement iframe = d.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
   d.switchTo().frame(iframe);
   WebElement tinymce = d.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
   tinymce.clear();
   tinymce.sendKeys("Hello, ckeditor!");
   ```

   **Result:** This code will go to the site and clear the editor, but won't put in any text into the CkEditor instance.
3. [AdvancedUserInteractions](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) -- eg.  Actions() in multiple variations

   ```
   textArea.click();
   new Actions(driver).sendKeys("Hello, ckeditor!").build().perform();
   ```

   and

   ```
   new Actions(driver).sendKeys(textArea, "Hello, ckeditor!").build().perform();
   ```

   and

   ```
   new Actions(driver).click(textArea).sendKeys("Hello, ckeditor!").build().perform();
   ```

   **Result**: These won't produce any text in the CkEditor
4. Switching iframes (as per Issue 3890 above) and using AdvancedUserInteractions

   Code similar to:

   ```
   driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
   textArea.click();
   new Actions(driver).sendKeys("Hello, ckeditor!").build().perform();
   ```

   **Result**: Throws error "*c.value is undefined*"
5. Using the Javascript and the CkEditor Api

   ```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) d;
   System.out.println("[debug] Set Text: " + setText);
   js.executeScript("CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('<p> "+ setText +"</p>');");
   ```

   **Result**: Excludes the '/' character when "*org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml*" is/isn't used to convert "*setText*" to Html entries. This solution also throws an "*ERROR: null*" on large strings.

Any ideas on things that I haven't tried? Fixes for things I have tried? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes Text areas are handled as Iframe where you have to switch to that frame and run JS command to type on it .

```
final WebDriver frame = driver.switchTo().frame(findElement(By.id("locator")); //any locator
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.body.innerHTML='" + TestValueThatYouWantToType + "'");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add wait statement after `tinymce.clear();` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

those facing this issue can refer to this URL:

http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.com/2012/03/fckeditor-switch-activeelement.html

I got mine issue fixed by referring this ;D